# How can I justify applying for 2 very different jobs within one organisation?

Tags: interviewing, reinterviewing

I have an interview upcoming at an organisation that I interviewed with (and got rejected) a few weeks ago.  The jobs are very different, 1 was in teaching and training and this one is in management.  It is the same interviewing panel however.  I have prepared for the interview and have all necessary qualities, skills and experience, but the one question I can not prepare for is the only inevitable one.  Something under the lines of, "why do you want to do this job when you were so passionate about the other one?"  Don't get me wrong, I would have preferred the other job, but would still really enjoy this one and be damn good at it.  They gave me excellent feedback from my last interview and said there was nothing they could tell me to improve on they just gave it to an internal applicant.  TIA x

Comment: A person cannot be passionate about more than one thing?  That is silly.  How can you be passionate about football if you are passionate about baseball.  How does one detract from the other?

Comment: Seems a bit personal, you *should* be able to apply to anything without them probing

Answer (score 5):

Do you regard the company highly? Do you regard the company highly enough that you'd take the job that you're less passionate about for a chance to join the company? Even though you are not as passionate about this job, is it still a job that you see as a good choice, that you want to do and that you can see yourself doing? If your answer to all these questions is yes, then there you have your answer.